# Subfigure numbering for Greek - XeLaTeX

Tags: numbering, subfloats, greek

I am writing a thesis in Greek. Everything compiles well and the produced document is the desired one except one little problem. The numbering on my subfigures is followed by a small rectangle, i.e. (α'rectangle'), (β'rectangle') etc. I'm posting my preamble concerning at least the language options. It is very annoying and any help will be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside, 12pt]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{Arial}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Arial}

\usepackage{float, subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[<options>]{figFile1}} \\
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[<options>]{figFile2}} \\
  \caption{}
  \label{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The same problem occurs if I use the `subfigure` package and substitute `\subfloat` with `\subfigure`.

Comment: It's good that you have posted the preamble, but a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would be of greater help. For example, what means do you use to produce subfigures?

Comment: You should also use `Script=Greek,Ligatures=TeX` for the Greek font. (`Ligatures=TeX` is an engine-neutral synonym for `Mapping=tex-text`.)

Comment: Andrey it complains that there is no TeX option in the Ligatures. I have used Script=Greek with no success

Comment: This is not related to your question. IMHO `xgreek` is more robust than `polyglossia`. Also, in case you want to have hyphenations both in greek and in english, since you are using xelatex, the easier way to achieve it is to use package `ucharclasses`. Check [here](http://www.mechpedia.gr/wiki/Hyphenation_-_%CE%A5%CF%86%CE%B5%CE%BD%CF%8E%CF%83%CE%B5%CE%B9%CF%82#xgreek_3)

Comment: Polyglossia seems to do the job for me. However, I will try your suggestion in order to have a more thorough look at the whole thing. Thank you very much for your time and effort

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the Greek numeral used for subfigures is followed by the character `ʹ` (U+0374 GREEK NUMERAL SIGN) that, apparently, your version of Arial misses.

You can avoid the problem by defining a substitution font for that character:

```
\newfontfamily\dejavusans{DejaVu Sans}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ʹ}{{\dejavusans ʹ}}
```

In case it's difficult for you to input the character, since we already know its code point in Unicode, the syntax is

```
\newunicodechar{^^^^0374}{{\dejavusans^^^^0374}}
```

Choose a font that's available in your system. I've used DejaVu Sans, but perhaps Linux Biolinum O is good as well.

Don't use `subfigure`: it's obsolete.

Comment: egreg don't I have to DeclareUnicodeCharacter first in order to show which character to change ?

Comment: ...and again it does not seem to work either with DejaVu Sans ... compiled ok but the bloody rectangle is still there !

Comment: That's `\newunicodechar`'s job. You need only to provide the Unicode character. And XeLaTeX works differently in this respect than pdfLaTeX, so `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` wouldn't work. Knowing the Unicode point you can say `\newunicodechar{^^^^0374}{{\dejavusans ^^^^0374}}`

Comment: I found that the character displayed is the 25A1 unicode char. I apply it as \newunicode{25A1}{\dejavusans '} and it says that there is an invalid argument. Sorry that I don't get it ... :(

Comment: I got the idea .. the only thing is how do I put the 0374 char as a first argument on the newunicodechar command?

Comment: @TH11 It was in my comment, but I added it also to the answer.

Comment: the command newunicodechar{^^^^0374}{{\dejavusans ^^^^0374}} compiles ok but the character is still there ... I think you showed me the way to go and I am grateful. Thank you very much

Comment: If I change the fonts of the document to DejaVu Sans in general everything is ok. Although the guidelines refer to Arial this shouldn't be much of a problem ! Your help was precious ! Thanks